# how can zookeeper cli create an empty node?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

The create command:

```
create [-s] [-e] path data
```

Unspecified the data field while creating node.
It is possible using ZooInspector

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: if zooinspector creates an empty node, then what is returned using get zkcli command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used the following command: `create /test ""`.

Get command on zkCli results:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 14] get /test

cZxid = 0x4
ctime = Fri Sep 07 09:38:31 IRDT 2018
mZxid = 0x4
mtime = Fri Sep 07 09:38:31 IRDT 2018
pZxid = 0x4
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 0
numChildren = 0
```

Finally, I download the zooInspector to check how it works and I create two znodes: fromcli and fromInspector. Accordingly, results are presented:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 20] ls /
[fromInspector, zookeeper, fromcli]
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 21] get /fromcli

cZxid = 0x23
ctime = Fri Sep 07 11:11:39 IRDT 2018
mZxid = 0x23
mtime = Fri Sep 07 11:11:39 IRDT 2018
pZxid = 0x23
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 0
numChildren = 0
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 22] get /fromInspector

cZxid = 0x24
ctime = Fri Sep 07 11:12:01 IRDT 2018
mZxid = 0x24
mtime = Fri Sep 07 11:12:01 IRDT 2018
pZxid = 0x24
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 0
numChildren = 0
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, but nodes which are actually empty return a null instead of a blank line

Comment: @J.Doe It seems that zooInspector returns empty for a created empty node. I had created the node and have not specified any data to it. is that exactly the process you do to create one you mean in zooInspector?

Comment: well, the zooInspector did not work. But the case is I found that the kafka's nodes which are not leaves are actually return null by using get command

Comment: Actually, your last comment is ambiguous, but It seems that you mean something which is not related to the context of this question. is it true? is your question answered? Next, you can submit a new question which discusses kafka and zookeeper.

Comment: It is not the kafka's problem, see the last picture

Comment: but how are you sure it has not been created by `create /config/topics null`?

Comment: if use create /config/topics null, zooInspector will show null , not blank. Actually, you will create a node which data is string "null".